# How can I load a .pem certificate in c# from file?

Tags: c#, openssl, x509certificate, pem, pfx

**Context**

I have a pfx certificate file. I can successfully load it to an `X509Certificate2` class using the following code:

```
var path = "mycert.pfx"
var password = "mypassword";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, password);
```

For some reasons I would like to use .pem format instead of binary format. So I've converted my "mycert.pfx" to "mycert.pem" using the following OpenSSL command:

```
pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out mycert.pem -nodes
```

**Question**

How can I load my converted mycert.pem in a similar way as I successfully loaded the mycert.pfx? The following code give me a CryptographicException saying "Cannot find the requested object." (note: this is not an io exception about file not found)

```
var path = "mycert.pem"
var password = "mypassword";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, password);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't support PKCS#12 in PEM (Base64) format. You must use PKCS#12 files in binary encoding only.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5 has new method
`X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile()`

Comment: [Documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompemfile) for convenience.